Proving an Inequality in Hilbert Space: $\int_0^1 \chi_{[t,\infty)}(T) dt \le T$ for $T\ge 0$
Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ denotes the set of all bounded operators on $\mathcal H$. An element $T\in \mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ is positive, we write $T\ge 0$ if $\langle Tx,x\rangle\ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathcal H$. Let $T$ be a positive element of $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$. Using functional calculus define the elements $\chi_{[t,\infty)}(T)$ in $\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$, where $t\ge 0$ in $\mathbb R$ and $\chi_{[t,\infty)}$ is the indicator function on $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ defined as:
$$\chi_{[t,\infty)}(s):=\begin{cases} 1,& s\ge t\\ 0,& s<t.\end{cases}$$ We call $\chi_{[t,\infty)}(T)$, the spectral projection of $T$ on $[t,\infty)$, for all $t\ge 0.$ I want to show that,
$$\int_0^1 \chi_{[t,\infty)}(T) dt\le T.$$
My approach: So, basically in classical sense we know that:
$$\chi_{[t,\infty)}(s):=\begin{cases} 1,& s\ge t\\ 0,& s<t\end{cases}=\chi_{(0,s]}(t).$$
Let us now calculate the integration as follows:
$$\begin{align*} \int_0^1 \chi_{[t,\infty)}(s)dt =\int_0^1\chi_{(0,s]}(t) dt =\begin{cases}\displaystyle \int_0^1dt=1,&\text{ if } s\ge 1 \\ \displaystyle\int_0^sdt=s,& \text{ if } s<1. \end{cases} \end{align*}$$ Thus we have, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \chi_{[t,\infty)}(s)dt\le s$. Now I want to show same this in operator field level. To show that, we need to show
$$\left\langle \left(\int_0^1 \chi_{[t,\infty)}(T)\right)x,x\right\rangle\le \langle Tx,x\rangle,~\forall x\in \mathcal H,\text{ that is } \int_0^1 \left\langle\left(\chi_{[t,\infty)}(T)\right)x,x\right\rangle\le \langle Tx,x\rangle,~\forall x\in \mathcal H.$$ I am unable to proceed from here. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your time and effort.

I suspect that it would be easiest to show that
$$
T = \int_0^\infty \chi_{[t,\infty)}(T),dt,
$$
so that $T - \int_0^1  \chi_{[t,\infty)}(T),dt$ can be expressed as an integral

According to your calculations $$\int\limits_0^1\chi_{[t,\infty)}(T)\,dt=f_1(T)$$ where $f_1(t)=t\,\chi_{[0,1]}(t)+\chi_{(1,\infty)}(t).$ We have $T=f(T),$ where $f(t)=t.$ As $0\le f_1(t)\le f(t)$ the conclusion follows.
